# How to change cell value in hyperlink destination Workbook (Google Spreadsheet) after hyperlink clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, hyperlink

I put the hyperlink in column B in the "Data" Workbook "Test 2" (link to the file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eh-gB8F7rPemK1MLpLcH9fYPzZUfp2fnGEBEwiKTpa4/edit#gid=0). If clicked, the hyperlink headed to the "CP" sheet in the "Test 3" workbook (link to the file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fi1deDpmlCB6v2EsoreTzSNN3ZzGyeinLArbAy31Mdw/edit#gid=0). ChatGPT helped me to make the "Google Spreadsheet" script which if the hyperlink is clicked will change the value of A1 cells in the "CP" Workbook "Test 3" using the value of column A which is parallel to the hyperlink which is clicked in column B on Sheet "Data" Workbook " Test 2 ". But still the script didnt work. Please, can someone find the problem and help it fixed (you can edit the workbook "Tes 2" and "Tes 3")? The script is below :

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fi1deDpmlCB6v2EsoreTzSNN3ZzGyeinLArbAy31Mdw/edit#gid=0")').build();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;
  var value = cell.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Data" && cell.getColumn() == 2 && value.indexOf("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fi1deDpmlCB6v2EsoreTzSNN3ZzGyeinLArbAy31Mdw/edit#gid=0") == 0) {
    var url = value.replace(/=HYPERLINK\("(.*)"\)/, "$1");
    var match = url.match(/\/d\/(.*)\//);
    var workbookId = match[1];
    var sheetId = url.match(/gid=(\d+)/)[1];
    var row = cell.getRow();
    var valueToCopy = sheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();
    var targetWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(workbookId);
    var targetSheet = targetWorkbook.getSheetByName("CP");
    var rangeToUpdate = targetSheet.getRange("A1");
    rangeToUpdate.setValue(valueToCopy);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

the value of A1 cells in the "CP" Workbook "Test 3" changes into the value of column A which is parallel to the hyperlink which is clicked in column B on Sheet "Data" Workbook " Test 2 "

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 3 questions. 1. About `change cell value in hyperlink destination Workbook (Google Spreadsheet) after hyperlink clicked`, I think that when a hyperlink of the cell is clicked, the URL is opened. How about this? 2. In your script, it seems that column "B" of "Data" sheet is checked. Do you want to run your script by editing column "B" of "Data" sheet?

Comment: 3. I cannot understand `the value of A1 cells in the "CP" Workbook "Test 3" changes into the value of column A which is parallel to the hyperlink which is clicked in column B on Sheet "Data" Workbook " Test 2 "`. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: I want the script run after I click the hyperlink and changes value of the A1 cell in the "CP" Workbook "Test 3" as the value of cells in column A that parallel to the clicked hyperlinks in column B

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About `I want the script run after I click the hyperlink`, I think that when a hyperlink of the cell is clicked, the URL is opened. How about this? Are you required to run the script by clicking the URL? And, I cannot understand `changes value of the A1 cell in the "CP" Workbook "Test 3" as the value of cells in column A that parallel to the clicked hyperlinks in column B`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes I want to run the script by clicking the URL, which after the script is run, it will automatically change the value of A1 cell on "CP" sheet in "Test 3" workbook

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I want to run the script by clicking the URL, which after the script is run`, I think that when a hyperlink of the cell is clicked, the URL is opened. By this, the script cannot be run. How about this? For example, do you change the method for running the script?

Comment: In this case I believe it will not be possible to achieve what you want, your current code expects a change to be made as it's an `onEdit` simple trigger, usually this trigger expects a change to be made in order to make the changes, clicking a link in a sheet is not really a change made on the spreadsheet, you will have to analyze a different behavior so you can achieve what you want as clicking links won't kick the `onEdit` trigger.